Error while installing sklearn.linear_model with pip
am trying to install scikit-learn and pandas using pip on my Windows machine, but I keep encountering the following error. I tried reinstalling pip, but the issue persists. Here’s what I’ve done so far:
C:\Windows\System32> pip install scikit-learn
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached scikit_learn-1.5.1.tar.gz (7.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [71 lines of output]
      Collecting meson-python>=0.16.0
        Using cached meson_python-0.16.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.1 kB)
      Collecting Cython>=3.0.10
        Using cached Cython-3.0.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
      Collecting numpy>=2.0.0rc2
        Using cached numpy-2.1.1-cp311-cp311-mingw_x86_64.whl
      Collecting scipy>=1.6.0
        Using cached scipy-1.14.1.tar.gz (58.6 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [40 lines of output]
        + meson setup C:\Users\Nhoxboon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vye30m4u\scipy_7ccac87e7a8d4346b9d9d86617c5a860 C:\Users\Nhoxboon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vye30m4u\scipy_7ccac87e7a8d4346b9d9d86617c5a860\.mesonpy-f5huf210 -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=C:\Users\Nhoxboon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vye30m4u\scipy_7ccac87e7a8d4346b9d9d86617c5a860\.mesonpy-f5huf210\meson-python-native-file.ini
        The Meson build system
        Version: 1.5.1
        Source dir: C:\Users\Nhoxboon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vye30m4u\scipy_7ccac87e7a8d4346b9d9d86617c5a860
        Build dir: C:\Users\Nhoxboon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vye30m4u\scipy_7ccac87e7a8d4346b9d9d86617c5a860\.mesonpy-f5huf210
        Build type: native build
        Project name: scipy
        Project version: 1.14.1
        C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 13.2.0 "cc (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.2.0")
        C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.41
        C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (gcc 13.2.0 "c++ (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.2.0")
        C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld.bfd 2.41
        Cython compiler for the host machine: cython (cython 3.0.11)
        Host machine cpu family: x86_64
        Host machine cpu: x86_64
        Program python found: YES (C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python.exe)
        Did not find pkg-config by name 'pkg-config'
        Found pkg-config: NO
        Run-time dependency python found: YES 3.11
        Program cython found: YES (C:\Users\Nhoxboon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dpiy_zy6\overlay\bin\cython.EXE)
        Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: YES
        Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-function: YES
        Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-conversion: YES
        Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-misleading-indentation: YES
        Library m found: YES

        ..\meson.build:84:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['ifort'], ['gfortran'], ['flang'], ['pgfortran'], ['g95']]
        The following exception(s) were encountered:
        Running `ifort --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
        Running `ifort -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
        Running `gfortran --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
        Running `gfortran -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
        Running `flang --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
        Running `flang -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
        Running `pgfortran --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
        Running `pgfortran -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
        Running `g95 --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
        Running `g95 -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

        A full log can be found at C:\Users\Nhoxboon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vye30m4u\scipy_7ccac87e7a8d4346b9d9d86617c5a860\.mesonpy-f5huf210\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: metadata-generation-failed

      Encountered error while generating package metadata.

      See above for output.

      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for details.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.


Tried pip install scikit-learn and pip install pandas but received the same error.

Tried deleting pip and reinstalling, but no changes.

Tried with a different package (pandas), but got the same error.



I also try delete Msys2 then redownload but still got this error
